# How to generate javascript stacktrace?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, printstacktrace

Any suggestions on how to, in a cross-browser way, generate a stack trace in javascript?

Newer browsers, Chrome and Firefox, expose a console object that allows stack traces to be generated.  This method does not provide a method for storing the stack trace to a variable.

https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace
Works quite nicely, but it makes separate ajax requests to load script files included as part of the trace.  This seems to be a common method in trace libraries.  I'm guessing that browsers do not expose enough information to generate a meaningful stack-trace(line numbers, function names, file names, arguments, etc).

Comment: You are correct that IE9- (let's face it, that probably what we're having trouble with here) doesn't give much useful information. One could get the file and line number from `window.onerror` except that only fires some of the time and the line number is sometimes wrong.

Comment: Yes, as usual, IE is the problem child.  I'm stuck supporting IE7 for which the onerror event's line number and function name information is terrible. It can still be useful; I use it to write logs for uncaught errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Error object and check it for a stack member. Adapted from [Code Overtones](http://www.codeovertones.com/2011/08/how-to-print-stack-trace-anywhere-in.html):

```
var e = new Error('dummy');
var stack = e.stack.replace(/^[^\(]+?[\n$]/gm, '') // remove lines without '('
  .replace(/^\s+at\s+/gm, '') // remove prefix text ' at '
  .split('\n');
console.log(stack);
```

Error.stack is documented in [Mozilla's reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype).

Answer (score 0):

[Airbrake provides a JavaScript library for logging stacktraces](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js) to your Airbrake account or Errbit server.

I don't get stack traces in IE, and others can be imperfect, but it definitely looks like it's along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  I already have a framework in place which can log to my server.  It's basically log4j in javascript.  The stack-trace generating code in the link you provided looks like it was borrowed from the project in my question.  I'm looking for other libraries for stack-trace generation.  The actual logging framework in use should be separate.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate javascript stacktrace using stacktrace.js

http://stacktracejs.com/

Also, you can refer to : http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/