# Is there a way to catch data from the console.trace() javascript?

Tags: javascript, console, virtual-machine, v8

This is my code:

```
 foo();
 var test;

  function foo(){
    function bar() {
      test = console.trace();
    }
    bar();
  }

  console.log(test);
```

It logs out the following:

```
bar VM246:9 
foo VM246:2 
(anonymous function) VM232:777 
InjectedScript._evaluateOn VM232:710 
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap VM232:626 
InjectedScript.evaluate VM246:12 
undefined
```

So, according to the logs the trace while test is `undefined`.

Is there a way to catch data from `console.trace()`?

Lets say, I need the number `5` for the `bar` and number `7` for the `foo`.

Comment: I think you're actually looking for [How to generate javascript stacktrace?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13480558/1048572)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller/3444831#3444831